# Помогите с пониманием клиент-сервер (если клиенты разные) ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

Всем доброй ночи ! Прошу помощи так как не могу понять смысл задачи :
Задача создать программу учёта автомобилей, выборка авто, цены на авто, продажа. Дополнение : клиент должен быть как десктопный (WinForms) так и с web-мордой (ASP.NET(MVC)) !
В общем некоторые детали почти понятны на абстрактом уровне, берём БД ставим её на сервер, а к ней пишем клиента на WinForms но как быть с ASP.NET ? Что такое Веб-морда и как она подключится к приложению это мне вообще не понятно, то есть это как бы сайт-клиент который использует эту БД с машинами ? Кто нибуть может мне подсказать порядок действий что с начала нужно делать что почитать и как это всё собрать в кучу !
Буду ОЧЕНЬ БЛАГОДАРНА ВСЕМ ДОБРЫМ ЛЮДЯМ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу пример классической трёхуровневой архитектуры приложения. В этом случае *"сервером"* считается не база данных, а серверное приложение, которое выполняет обращения к базе данных и предоставляет [API](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) для клиентов. *"Клиентом"* в свою очередь, может быть всё что угодно - десктопное приложение, веб-приложение, всевозможные мобильные приложения и т.д. Клиенты выполняют обращения к серверному приложению, испольюзуя его API. Советую ознакомится с [небольшим обзором на википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) (схема позаимствована именно оттуда)

---

[image]

---

Серверное приложение может представлять собой обычное консольное приложение, которое обрабатывает запросы от клиентов. Если вы используете .NET, то связь между клиентами и сервером можно организовать с помощью технологий WCF, WebAPI и т.д.
Клиенты (т.е. WinForms-приложение и Web-приложение) будут выполнять обращения не напрямую к базе данных, а к серверному приложению. А оно уже, в свою очередь, выполнит обращение к базе, если посчитает нужным, и вернет требуемые данные.

**P.S.** Зачем всё это было придумано, писать не буду: читайте [википедию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0).

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО ! Вы очень доступно ответили, благодарю ! От всей души желаю вам удачи во всём :)

Comment: @Алина_Климова, рад, что смог помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй технологию [LightSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff852064.aspx), инструмент по умолчанию входит в Visual Studio 2012, позволяет создавать трехуровневые приложения, как для десктопа, так и для WEB, при этом необязательно уметь  программировать. Все делается посредством визуального редактора, твою задачу можно за вечер решить с помощью LightSwitch.
P.S.
[Пошаговое руководство](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee256749.aspx) по созданию приложения